# In a simple hypothesis vs composite hypothesis test, are the p-values the same?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

In a simple hypothesis test, we have something like $H_0 = 5$ and $H_A = 10$ while in a composite hypothesis test we have something like $H_0 = 5$ and $H_A >5$. Since the p-value is defined to be the probability, assuming the null hypothesis is true, of observing a result at least as extreme as the test statistic, would the p-values for the simple and composite case be the same (assuming the same data)? I ask this because we are using the null distribution, which is the same for both. Thank you!

Comment: How to you deal with $H_0:\mu=5$ Vs  $057_1: \mu = 10$ ?